# How to get crs_description from EPSG-Code?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, expression, qgis-expression

I'm searching for an expression in QGIS to get the description of a CRS

Assume I have following table:

| Area | EPSG | desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | EPSG:31258 |  |
| A2 | EPSG:31255 |  |

Now I want to fill in the "CRS-Description" in the field desc... is this possible?

I only can find `@project_crs_description` which returns the Project CRS Description

Anyone an idea?

Comment: You could write a script to get the description.  From here: https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#qgis.core.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

Comment: What information do you want returned as a description? and are you interested in CRS defined by any authority or are you just interested in EPSG authority CRS codes

Comment: I want the same information as @project_crs_description provides for the project CRS on

Comment: @nmtoken Thank you. That looks very promising. Someday i ll have to start a basic python course to know how to use this kind of scripts in QGIS